# Is there a way to point TestCafe at "localhost" instead of the machine IP?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, localhost, ip-address, testcafe

I've noticed that the browser always connects to the computer by way of IP address. I suspect a new firewall is blocking this connection for me. Other services of mine work when I connect to them as localhost. Is there a way to have the browser launched by TestCafe connect to localhost instead of the IP address?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `hostname` flag. Please see: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--hostname-name

Comment: Thanks. This has helped to workaround some of my issues.